# How to override Windows 8 Hostname (computer name) with different IP address?

Tags: windows-8, ip, hostname

I want resolve Windows' hostname (computer name) to another IP. `127.0.0.1 myhostname` in hosts file doesn't work. `ping myhostname` shows that it have ethernet adapter IP (`192.168.1.2`).

It works in Windows 7, but not in Windows 8.

Any ideas?

Comment: If drop ethernet connection, it resolves to 127.0.0.1. But still doesn't want read hosts file (e.g 8.8.8.8 myhostname doesn't work).

Comment: What file (please provide the full path) are you editing?  Can we see its contents?

Comment: I edit Windows hosts file. It works for any other name except windows hostname.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us a little bit more of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: It works in Windows 7, could someone confirm it works on Windows 8?

Comment: Wait a second, are you saying you're trying to remap your computer's network ID to something else?  If that's the case, you may be running into [Windows Defender monitoring your hosts file](http://www.howtogeek.com/122404/how-to-block-websites-in-windows-8s-hosts-file/)

Comment: It's not the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The hosts file is used to map

> hostnames to IP addresses.

It **will NOT Map IP addresses to hostnames** but it can be used to produce hostname "aliases".

The hosts file produces the internal equivalent of A and PTR records from the DNS, i.e. mapping of hostname to IP address .

For adding a alias name to a server in the hosts file you have to make the following structure:

In the first column you have to add the IP-Address, in the second column the host-name and in the third column you have to add the desired alias-name. Any subsequent columns are alias for that host. In the example's second line the IP-Address 192.168.0.2 is for the server test.server.com and another name for it is test.

For example:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost            test.server.com
192.168.0.2     test2.server.com     test2
192.168.0.3     another.server.com   another
```

This uses the hosts file on your computer.  You will need to edit the hosts file on each computer that will use the alias; if you want to make this a global change, you need to use a real DNS server.

Comment: _In the example's second line the IP-Address 192.168.0.2 is for the server test.server.com and another name for it is test._ It's not true, if you try to access test.server.com you will get 127.0.0.1. On topic: it doesn't help me to change hostname IP.

Comment: The Hosts file will NOT map IP-->Hostname.  It goes the other way.  You CAN setup a DNS server...

Comment: Why should I use DNS server for SINGLE machine?

Comment: Well, could you explain why 127.0.0.1 justanotherhostname.com works fine, but 127.0.0.1 myhostname doesn't?

Comment: Nope, it's exactly ontopic.